# How are pointers evaluated in a C++ boolean expression?

Tags: c#, c++, object, boolean

I'm converting an old Borland C++ application to C# .NET

There's this class that looks like it's basically just a Doubly Linked List.

One of the methods looks like this:

```
MessagePtr CheckMessageList::First(MessageSourceTable _source)
{
  MessagePtr
    message = First();
  bool
    done = false;

  while (message && !done)
  {
    done = (bool) (message->SourceTable() == _source);
    if (!done)
      message = Next();
  }

  return (message);
}
```

I don't understand how `while (message)` is evaluated though.

In C# I have this:

```
public CheckMessage Fist(enums.MessageSourceTable table)
{
    CheckMessage message = First();
    bool done = false;

    while (message && !done)
    {
        done = message.SourceTable.Equals(table);

        if (!done)
            message = Next();
    }

    return message;
}
```

Which is invalid since it doesn't know how to handle that while statement.

I have virtually no experience with C++. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

edit; would this be the same thing, basically?

```
public CheckMessage Fist(enums.NYMSMessageSourceTable table)
{
    foreach (CheckMessage cm in _list)
    {
        if (cm.SourceTable.Equals(table))
            return cm;
    }

    return Last();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ pointers have implicit conversions to `bool`, where a pointer is "falsy" if it is equal to `nullptr` and "truthy" otherwise. So

```
while(message)
```

is equivalent to

```
while(message != nullptr)
```

Comment: `typedef CheckMessage* MessagePtr;` is defined between the `CheckMessage` and `CheckMessageList` classes that I'm working on. So for C# that'd basically be the same as `while (message != null)` ?

Comment: Worth mentioning too: pretty much all built-in types have an implicit conversion to `bool` that compares to zero. For pointer types and pointer-to-member types, zero happens to evaluates as `nullptr` (C# `null`). For integer types, floating point types, enumeration types, the comparison to zero is still available implicitly. `a && b` means the same thing as `a != 0 && b != 0` for all built-in types.